# What does ?/ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I just stumbled across this piece of code:

```
if source[0] != ?/
  source = compute_asset_path(source, options)
end
```

What's this "`?/`"? I've never seen writing strings this way.

```
$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > ?/
=> "/"
```

Apparently it works for single characters only:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > ?a
 => "a" 
2.0.0p247 :002 > ?foo
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected '?'
```

What does `?` mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`?` is used to represent single character string literals. Like `?a`,`?b` but not `?ab`.

To answer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225374/what-does-mean-in-ruby/22225408#comment33746510_22225408) of OP :

Yes, they are.

```
irb(main):001:0> ?x + 'y'
=> "xy"
irb(main):002:0> 'x' + 'y'
=> "xy"
```

Comment: Whether it is single quote or double quote, it does not make difference. In order to interpolate, you need `#{}`, which cannot be written in a single character anyway.

Comment: @sawa You are correct.

Comment: But what's the actual difference between `?a` and `"a"`? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: `?a` is left probably only for compatibility with legacy code. Other than that, there is no practical value.

Comment: @simone it is very useful in `code-golf`(http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/play-a-sound-any-sound/10555#10555) and internal ruby jokes, like `almost_sinatra` (https://github.com/rkh/almost-sinatra/blob/master/almost_sinatra.rb)

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.8.x series, it return ASCII value

```
alok@alok-desktop:~$ rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p370
Using /home/alok/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370
alok@alok-desktop:~$ irb
1.8.7-p370 :001 > ?F
 => 70
```

In Ruby 1.9+ it returns same character string

```
1.9.2-p320 :018 > ?A
 => "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$>  "/" == ?/ 
=> true
```

another version of string but shorter :)
`also true: %{/}`